# NativeScript Place Disclosure Indicator on ListView Rows for iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, typescript, angular, nativescript

I have a this structure in my NativeScript page:

```
<ListView #listView [items]="summaryData" row="0">
    <Template let-item="item">
        <GridLayout columns="180, *, auto" rows="auto, *">
            <Label [text]="item.name" col="0" class="summary"></Label>
            <Label [text]="item.value" col=1 class="summary"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </Template>
</ListView>
```

For the iOS side I'd like to use the native disclosure indicator for the table view cell. I was able to remove the separator lines by using the following code:

```
@ViewChild("listView") listView: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    this.summaryData = this._summaryService.load();
    if (this._page.ios) {
        let iosListView = <ListView>this.listView.nativeElement;
        iosListView.ios.separatorStyle = 0; // Removes the separator lines.
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get to the individual rows aka `UITableViewCell` to set the accessoryType value. Is this possible with NativeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `itemLoading` of the ListView and then change the `accessoryType` there. So your html should be something like:

```
<ListView #listView [items]="summaryData" (itemLoading)="onItemLoading($event)" row="0">
    <Template let-item="item">
        <GridLayout columns="180, *, auto" rows="auto, *">
            <Label [text]="item.name" col="0" class="summary"></Label>
            <Label [text]="item.value" col=1 class="summary"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </Template>
</ListView>
```

And then in your component to have:

```
import {ItemEventData} from "ui/list-view";

onItemLoading(args: ItemEventData) {
   if (args.ios) {
       // args.ios is instance of UITableViewCell
       args.ios.accessoryType = 1; // UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator
   }
}
```